Firestore in Datastore mode - will non-transaction queries of an Entity be strongly consistent after that Entity is updated in a transaction?
Using Firestore in Datastore mode, if my application updates a property of an Entity in a transaction, will that update be immediately visible to all reads of that entity that are not in a transaction?
I'm thinking of a situation where an Entity gets updated in a transaction and right after that transaction successfully finishes, other clients query for that exact same Entity without using a transaction. Will those query reads be strongly consistent and immediately reflect the new updates? Or could they return an older pre-transaction version of the Entity?
The documentation says "All Datastore queries are now strongly consistent unless you explicitly request eventual consistency" but I am not sure if this applies to my example above.
